# UNEXPECTED T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING Error

Tags: php

I am getting an UNEXPECTED T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in this line

```
 $portfolio_html.= '<li> <a href=" "><img height="54" width="60" 
  src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'"></a></li>';
```

Can any body help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started your comment /* before your concatenation . to resolve, add a . after a href=" ' on line 1, or move your starting block comment to after the period.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php
<?php
echo 'a' 'b';
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 2
```

You forgot a period between your string literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
$portfolio_html.= "<li> <a href='" . HTTP_SERVER . $ilpage['portfolio'] . "?cmd=zoom&amp;item=" . $portfolio_item['id'] . "&amp;id=" . $portfolio_item['user_id'] ."><img height='54' width='60' src='images/portfolio_uploads/orig_" .$portfolio_item['image']. "'></a></li>';
```

check this out. and i have removed the comment form it.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not proper , check your href you are adding comment
try this

```
 $portfolio_html.='<li> <a href=" ' . HTTP_SERVER . $ilpage['portfolio'] .     
 '?cmd=zoom&amp;item=' . $portfolio_item['id'] . '&amp;id=' . $portfolio_item['user_id'] 
 .'"><img height="54" width="60" src="images/portfolio_uploads
  /orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'"></a></li>';
```